# "'overloaded-function': illegal sizeof operand" при попытке определить размер функции

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь определить размер функции. Компилятор выдает ошибку:

> error C2070: 'overloaded-function': illegal sizeof operand

Почему? Вот код:

```
void func() {}
int main() {
    int a;
    a = sizeof(func);   
}
```

Почему такая ошибка? Как определить размер функции?

Comment: Что значит размер функции? Размер указателя на функцию? Или подразумевается сколько байтов занимает сам код функции? Тогда, боюсь, без черной магии не обойтись, но можно попробовать арифметику указателей - подряд идущие функции наверняка идут подряд в исполняемом файле.

Comment: да, мне нужно узнать, сколько байт памяти занимает код функции

Comment: Размер функции -- штука малополезная. Например, оптимизатор может заинлайнить вашу функцию и выкинуть её из исполнимого файла.

Сдаётся мне, вы избрали неправильный путь для своей цели. Расскажите, чего именно вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Вот мне тоже интересно зачем это нужно. Каков практический смысл?

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего разобрать вывод утилиты nm для объектного файла с этой функцией.

nm для винды есть в составе  MinGW. Но наверняка можно найти родной аналог.

Comment: @avp, можно и по .map смотреть. Но что-то подсказывает, что хотят определять в рантайме :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Поставьте метки до и после функции (например, в виде других функций), получите их адреса и вычислите разницу. Прим: надеюсь, понятно, что в зависимости от кучи факторов этот размер может быть самым разным для одного и того же исходника.

2) Сгенерируйте объектник и посмотрите в нём. См. "Прим" к 1)

3) Сгенерите ассемблерный исходник и посчитайте вручную.  См. "Прим" к 1)

Answer (score 0):

void не имеет размера. Невозможно определить размер, будет исключение.

Comment: разумеется, `void` не имеет размера, но тип выражения `func` вовсе не `void`.